# Focus to scroll for input ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, ionic-framework

I have a website that is written using Ionic/AngularJD.
I am opening the website on a tablet that runs windows in the chrome browser. When I click on input field in this tablet, the scroll to focus does not happen. How do I achieve this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. BTW, its not an app and it is a website.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Make it a bit more readable

Comment: Do you have [ionic-keyboard-plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) installed? It fixes such issues with various devices.